# Matching full text from string with php regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Lets say I have sentence like this: "Hello world this is a test". In this sentence I want to match with "world test" or "hell this" something like that. How can I do this with preg_match? This is probably something like mysql fulltext search.

```
$str = "Hello world this is a test";
$src1 = "world test";
$src1 = "hell this";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\b` for defining boundaries as

```
/\b(world\stest|hell\sthis)/
```

**Explanation**

1. `\b` assert position at a word boundary
2. `(world\stest|hell\sthis)`
   this'll check for `world test` or `hell this`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = "Hello world this is a test";
$src1 = 
$src1 = str_replace(' ','.*',$src1);
preg_match("/(.*$src1.*)/i", $str, $results);

print_r($results);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this, and looks like its working for me:

```
$searchword = str_replace(" ", "|", $src1);
preg_match_all("/$searchword/i", $str)
```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should combine two expressions: `world.*test` and `hell.*this`. Resulting expression is `world.*test|hell.*this`. (FIY `.*` matches any number of any character).

PS: You can also consider using [CleanRegex](https://github.com/Danon/pattern):

```
$str = "Hello world this is a test";

if (pattern('world.*test|hell.*this')->matches($str)) 
{
    // Matched! :)
}
```